# How to pass dynamic queue name in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-5.0

Am having a CSV file with a list of active mq queue name.  Am trying to push messages to dynamic queue by reading the queue name from csv and setting it to my variable and passing that variable in jms point to point sampler as ${queueName}. The messages are not getting poster todynamic queue, instead it's getting posted to ${queueName

Answer (score 0):

As per your reply, Its clear your queue variable name doesn't get evaluated properly. 
I hope you can find the root cause for the issue by following below steps.

1. Check whether CSV file in a readable location, It should be on bin folder
2. Check for variable name spellings
3. Add a debug sampler in middle and check whether variable getting evaluated correctly
4. Install step-by-step plugin and debug the jmeter flow

Comment: I have used the same variable in sampler name and it's comes out correctly.  Only when am using it in JNDI request name, we're facing this issue

Comment: Check with 4 th step, https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-debugger should give clear idea whats actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the variable spelling is correct in both CSV Data config and the request where you are using the variable. This happens when there is no data available in the sheet or if there is a spell mistake in the variable.